# angular 2+ create pdf from html template

Tags: html, angular, firebase, pdf

Is there any way without server side scripts to generate a PDF file from a HTML template in Angular 4?

I have some input fields that the users fills out and I want to create a new PDF file every time the user wants to. I have a download button where the user can download the generated PDF to their device.

Since it's a small app just for optimization of a process I'm using Firebase for the database and Angular 4 for everything else.

Do I have to create a server side script for generating the PDF or is it possible to do it with the technologies I'm already using?

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything that will convert HTML to PDF that will work in the browser. Have you tried something like this: http://pdfmake.org/ There are various npm packages that might work in the browser but create the PDF from scratch.

Comment: @Notmfb thank you very much, I tried pdfmake and it works perfecty. It's the solution I wanted!